# Adf.ly tells me I need to enable cookies in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I'm using Chrome and using Firefox is not really an option.  I want to download stuff for Minecraft but Adf.ly is not working.  It tells me I need to enable cookies and I did but its still not working.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to download? I used to use Chrome to download a lot of Minecraft mods via adfly without problems, but it's been a few months since then.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you are using a proxy server that blocks cookies before your browser gets them. I would contact the network administrator to solve the situation or deactivate the proxy for adf.ly domains.